# Making sure a predicate function is valid in C++ templated function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, static-assert

When writing a function that accepts a predicate function, such as the one below; how can you ensure the predicate function is valid (i.e. the return type of `operator()` is valid)?

```
template <typename Predicate>
std::vector<SomeType> SearchList( Predicate func ) 
{
     std::vector<SomeType> vecResults;
     for( const auto& someObj : someTypeList )
     {
          if( func( someObj ) )
              vecResults.emplace_back( someObj );
     }

     return vecResults;
}
```

Looking around at the type-traits facility in C++11, I've discovered `std::is_convertible<From,To>`, which looks like it should help, although I'm not sure how to use it to check there is a suitable implicit conversion from `operator()` to `bool`. The only things I could think of were:

```
static_assert( std::is_convertible<Predicate(SomeType), bool>::value, "Predicate type must be convertible to bool" );
```

Or:

```
static_assert( std::is_convertible<Predicate::operator()(SomeType), bool>::value, "Predicate type must be convertible to bool" );
```

But neither of these seem to look correct to me.

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem... If the return type of `func( someObj )` is not convertible to `bool` then the code `if( func( someObj ) )` won't compile anyway... Or maybe you want to enforce that the return type is _exactly_ `bool`? Or give a custom error message?

Comment: @gx_: Probably so, but a `static_assert` generates a much nicer error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
#include <utility> // For std::declval<>()

static_assert(
    std::is_convertible<decltype(func(std::declval<SomeType>())), bool>::value,
    "Predicate's return type must be convertible to bool");
```

If you only have the type `Predicate` or do not want to use `func` in the expression:

```
static_assert(
    std::is_convertible<
        decltype(std::declval<Predicate&>()(std::declval<SomeType>())),
        bool>::value,
    "Predicate's return type must be convertible to bool");
```